# For-loop from scratch in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I've been looking around to find a way of creating a for-loop in Python, without using the word 'for' and so on.  **I would like to create a for-loop using def and not the built-in function. I basically want to create my own for-loop from scratch**

Code sample for creating len in python from scratch:

```
def L(list):        #code for len() function. 
  counter = 0       #uses counter and for-loop
  for n in list:    #to increment counter for each 
    counter += 1    #value in the entered list

print(counter)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: *Why*? What is the actual problem you need to solve by making your own "for"-like function? Right now this question is too much of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You have to use *some* looping construct.  The lowest-level is probably the `while` statement.  The only other alternative would be to use recursion, but that's a poor solution since it consumes stack space.

Comment: You might want to add more precision to what you want to do, seeing all three answers have a different interpretation of it

Comment: @TomKarzes functools.reduce() would also be naive "for loop" if the aim is to only count the elements in iterable :) `functools.reduce(lambda nth,_: nth+1, our_iterable , 0)`

Comment: Yes, there are lots of implied loop constructs you could use (`map`, `filter`, `min`, `max`, any type of comprehension, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop instead if you don't want to use the `for` loop:

```
def alternate_for(list):
     counter = 0
     n = len(list)
     while counter < n:
         do_something
         counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

OK first, you need to understand that `for` and `len` are very different things. len() is a builtin function. As a function, of course it can be reimplemented in python. It is just given for convenience's sake.

for is a keyword and a basic language feature. **It is not a function**. Therefore, you cannot reimplement it (unless for example, you are editing the interpreter). Nethertheless *you can create a function that does the same thing*

here is a sample using recursion:

```py
def for-loop(iterator, function):
   iterator = iter(iterator) #convert given iterable to iterator if not already done
   try:
      value = next(iterator)
   except StopIteration:
      return
   function(value)
   return for-loop(iterator, function) #recurse

#usage example :
for-loop(range(5), lambda x: print(x))
```

returns

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

If you don't understand this code, you might want to read about iterators, and what the python for really does, as well as recursion.

EDIT: Actually, I'm beggining to think this is a good exercice, since it teaches you about advanced language features and techniques such as iterators, recursion, lambda functions… If you want a good continuation of this exercice, you could implement the `else` (from the `for: else:` construct)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this may actually be what I'm looking for.

Comment: well you should test the code before accepting the answer because I wrote it without testing it

Comment: also, note that as mentioned in the comments, since tail-call optimization is not implemented in python, this recursive approach consumes stack-space, therefore you will not be able to write big loops with this (though it shouldn’t matter since it is just a toy implementation)